# Confusing with 12 hive concept

Tags: 2007

I am having a problem with Importing a site to another site collection and getting an exception and that question can be viewed here,

[Web Template Not found](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42970/getting-web-template-not-found-error-while-importing/42974#comment39576_42974)

I am bit confused with the concept of templates, If I am creating a Site Collection regardless of which custom template I use to create it, it should had access to all of the site templates in 12 hive (**Site Collections should or can share Web templates when needed ?**)

our 12 hive folder structure is something like this,

12

Config
Admisapi
isapi
Resources
Help
Bin
Template
Logs
HCCab

**Can someone explain what these folders are used for ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12 is sharepoint 2007, 14 is sharepoint 2010.

These are the dependencies of sharepoint, everything it requires to run.

When you deploy a complex solution you deploy to the correct area of the solution ie: layouts or Template, the core then uses these files correctly.

Think of the folder as the definition of the use of the files contained.

I won't list them all, this has been done before, so here is a link.

http://grounding.co.za/blogs/brett/archive/2008/03/24/sharepoint-get-to-know-the-directory-structure-in-the-12-hive.aspx

I hope this helps.