# where are all Web/Site template( Not Site Definitions) kept on hard drive

Tags: 2007, site-template, template

I know all site definitions are being kept at 12hive/Template/SiteTemplates....

but where are all web templates kept on hard disk that I see in Site Template Gallery..

its some how related to this question.

[Web Template Not Found](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42970/getting-web-template-not-found-error-while-importing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database as all other documents stored in any Document Libraries, except for the cases where you would use RBS.

Comment: I couldn't find any related table in relative Content Database where they store these templates, am afraid